# string Parameter should allow only alphanumaric and dot in Web api route attribute regular expression in .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have one method and in webapi, i am using swagger to call web api. In api request 'request type' parameter should allow only alphabets, numbers and dot(.).
i have tried below code but it is not working

```
 [HttpGet]
 [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(string))]
 [Route(@"testMethod/{requestType:regex(^[A-Za-z0-9. ]+$)}")]
 public IHttpActionResult testMethod(int mid,string requestType = "", )
 {
     //logic
 }
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a good error description. Please explain what you *expect* to happen and explain what happens *instead*.

Comment: You have an extra space character in your regular expression

Comment: if i pass the 'requestType' parameter value containing dot it should accept.(eg: test.xyz or test123). other than dot any other special characters it should not accept the request(eg: test@123 or test&xyz). I have tried with removing of extra space event accepting the request with dot

Answer (score 4):

In regular expressions, the dot usually is a placeholder for any character. Thus, you have to escape it. In .NET, this is done with a backslash: `A-Za-z0-9\.`

Answer (score 0):

This may work :

```
[a-zA-Z]|\d|\s|\.*
```